# Groovy iterate over Map

Tags: groovy

I am having a groovy `map` which holds this kinda values

```
Map testMap = [1:[1,1,1],2:[2,2,2]]
```

Here when I call `collect` function like this

```
testMap.collect {it.value}
```

I getting the `output` like

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

But I want the `output` as `[1,1,1,2,2,2]`

is their any `groovy` method to achieve this, `without using each` method

Comment: You should use collectMany groovy method instead, check my solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use groovy's [flatten()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29) method.

```
testMap.collect {it.value}.flatten()
```

Comment: even shorter `testMap*.value.flatten()`

Comment: @kunal, I'm doing like this only

Answer (score 7):

There is even simplier solution

```
 [1:[1,1,1],2:[2,2,2]].collectMany{it.value}
```

Answer (score 7):

A couple of the solutions here use the collect family, which is ok if you're doing mutations on the data, but in this case it's just grabbing all the values which would be better served using the spread operator on the values of the map

```
testMap*.value.flatten()
```

or with functions on the map

```
testMap.values().flatten()
```

Note it's `value` when spreading over each element of the map, and `values()` when asking the map directly in one go for the entries values.

Both of these read more as "getting values out of testMap" rather than collect which is usually used for mutations on the map.

It's a matter of style, but if you only use collect when you're going to mutate the data, you'll have more readable code.